# pseudo boolean modularity constraint?

Tags: sat

I have a constraint like d >= a ^ b ^ c, where a,b,c,d are binary, ^ is XOR.

Is this a pseudo boolean modularity constraint or not? Most Pseudo boolean modularity constraints I saw are with equality, which confuses me a lot.

My question is

1. what is this constraint, a pseudo boolean modularity or something else?
2. How can I turn it into a CNF

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn it into CNF using [the Tseitin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseitin_transformation).  Some SAT front-ends will do the transformation for you: for instance, the [STP solver](https://stp.github.io/) has native support for all of those operations and thus can handle the transformation for you.